# Is it possible to set SameSite=Strict cookie in webview_flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview

I'm using [`webview_flutter`](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) to render my website and [`webview_cookie_manager`](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_cookie_manager) to inject cookies to a webview.

```dart
final cookieManager = WebviewCookieManager();
final cookie = Cookie.fromSetCookieValue("set-cookie: foo=bar; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict; Path=/");
print(cookie);
cookieManager.setCookies([cookie]);
```

However, it seems `SameSite=Strict` is totally ignored: `print(cookie)` above prints

```
flutter: foo=bar; Path=/; HttpOnly
```

This is because [`Cookie`](https://api.dart.dev/be/180791/dart-io/Cookie-class.html) in `dart:io` doesn't have `sameSite` property (WHY??).

How can I inject `SameSite=Strict` cookie in a webview?